# Azure App Service - Offline Sync - PullAsync Transaction

Tags: android, ios, azure, xamarin, azure-mobile-services

I'm working on an App which uses Xamarin.Forms and Azure App Service.
The user must explicitly execute a data sync. When the user starts a data sync a lot of this methods are executed to get the current data from the server:

```
 await this.ISyncTable.PullAsync(queryId, query, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

My problem: The application can get into an inconsistent state. For example when the user closes the App before the data sync is completed. In this state the App is not usable.

Edit:

**To make it easier to understand: Let's assume i have a table "ToDoItem" and "ToDoCategory". The user starts a data sync. The data sync runs and the all ToDoItems are successfully retrieved . In the next step the data sync will get the ToDoCategories (another call to PullAsync) but before this the user closes the app. Now i have all ToDoItems but no ToDoCategories. But the App is not useable with no ToDoCategories. This is a really simple example. The data structure is much more complex in the real project. There are a lot of dependencies between the entities.**

**It is no solution to log the sync error / cancellation and prompt the user at the next app start for another sync. Assume on the next app start the user has no internet connection and cannot perform a data sync. I cannot lock the app until the next successful data sync.**

Is there a way to run multiple PullAsync operations in a transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to run multiple PullAsync operations in a transaction?

Short answer is no, there isn't. Set a flag in when all your PullAsync operations are complete, or keep track of which tables have synced successfully.

> It is no solution to log the sync error / cancellation and prompt the user at the next app start for another sync. Assume on the next app start the user has no internet connection and cannot perform a data sync. I cannot lock the app unitl the next successful data sync.

What is your app's expected behavior on the second run if the user started the sync but then left the app before sync completed? Finish the sync? Prompt the user to start again?

Also consider the app could probably continue syncing in the background after the user has left. In iOS you have to coordinate with the operating system using `UIApplication beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I think Microsoft should have such a feature directly in their SDK. Its not just the user closes the app. Maybe there is an network error during the sync. The main problem is that the data on the local device can be inconsistent when the sync aborts. In need a Rollback like feature to undo all changes in the local database during the incomplete sync. I will think about it and publish my solution here...

Comment: I agree, the SDK isn't a perfect fit for apps with multiple interdependent tables. You may want to create a custom API that returns the entire collection of data in one HTTP request and store the results locally, but then you're not taking advantage of the SDK's offline sync functionality.

Comment: See also Adrian Hall's book on building mobile apps with Azure Mobile Apps, in particular this section on object relationships: https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/relationships/ "we do not have transactions to allow the updating of multiple tables within the database at the same time. Each record in each table is updated individually. The push process that offline sync uses has major ramifications for how relationships between tables work. Specifically, only 1-way relationships will work in an offline sync world."

Answer (score 0):

> My problem: The application can get into an inconsistent state. For example when the user closes the App before the data sync is completed. In this state the App is not usable.

If you specify the query id (non-null), then you would use the **Incremental Sync** for pulling operations. As the official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-offline-data-sync#a-namehow-sync-worksahow-offline-synchronization-works) mentioned about Incremental Sync:

> the first parameter to the pull operation is a query name that is used only on the client. If you use a non-null query name, the Azure Mobile SDK performs an incremental sync. **Each time a pull operation returns a set of results, the latest updatedAt timestamp from that result set is stored in the SDK local system tables. Subsequent pull operations retrieve only records after that timestamp**.

After successfully retrieve the data and update to your local data store, then the client SDK would update/insert the `__config` table with the latest updatedAt timestamp from the pulled result along with the id equals `deltaToken|{table-name}|{query-id}` for your SQLite db as follows:

[image]

Additionally, after retrieve the records, the client SDK would execute the following sql statement for updating your local data store:

Assuming you have retrieved 50 records for `TodoItem` table.

> BEGIN TRANSACTION
>
> INSERT OR IGNORE INTO [TodoItem] ([id]) VALUES (@p0),(@p1),(@p2),(@p3),(@p4),(@p5),(@p6),(@p7),(@p8),(@p9),(@p10),(@p11),(@p12),(@p13),(@p14),(@p15),(@p16),(@p17),(@p18),(@p19),(@p20),(@p21),(@p22),(@p23),(@p24),(@p25),(@p26),(@p27),(@p28),(@p29),(@p30),(@p31),(@p32),(@p33),(@p34),(@p35),(@p36),(@p37),(@p38),(@p39),(@p40),(@p41),(@p42),(@p43),(@p44),(@p45),(@p46),(@p47),(@p48),(@p49)
>
> UPDATE [TodoItem] SET [Text] = @p0,[UserId] = @p1 WHERE [id] = @p2
>
> UPDATE [TodoItem] SET [Text] = @p0,[UserId] = @p1 WHERE [id] = @p2
>
> .
>
> .
>
> COMMIT TRANSACTION
>
> BEGIN TRANSACTION
>
> INSERT OR IGNORE INTO [__config] ([id]) VALUES (@p0)
>
> UPDATE [__config] SET [value] = @p0 WHERE [id] = @p1
>
> COMMIT TRANSACTION

The default `MaxPageSize` for `pullasync` is 50, the client would automatically send multiple requests if three has more data. Note after retrieve records in page, the retrieved data would update to your local data store, then the next page request would be sent. Per my understanding, if the user closes the App before the data sync is completed, the data would not be updated to the latest, when the user open the app again, then the missing data would be updated to your data store based on the latest updatedAt timestamp.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i think that this is not the solution related to my problem.  To make it easier to understand: Let's assume i have a Table "ToDoItem" and "ToDoCategory". The user starts a data sync. The data sync runs and the all ToDoItems are  successfully retrieved . In the next step the data sync will get the ToDoCategories (another call to PullAsync) but before this the user closes the app. Now i have all ToDoItems but no ToDoCategories. But the App is not useable with no ToDoCategories. I updated my first post.