# Azure App Service - Possible not correct solvable sync conflict?

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin, cross-platform, offlineapps

We currently develop a cross platform app with Xamarin.Forms and Azure App Service with offline sync. But from time to time  the offline sync loses some data. It is very hard to debug because it is not reproducible. Here are our thoughts how this can happen.

*Do you guys think that this is a possible scenario in Azure App Service? If yes, is there any good solution for this problem?*

**Scenario:**

1. Data record version in client: 001. Data record version in server: 001. So both are the same.
2. User (client side) do changes on the data record. Client version of the data record is still 001 (because Azure App Service manages the version number server side).
3. User synchronizes the data with the server. The changed data record is successfully committed to the server. Server version number is now 002. Client version number is still 001.
4. Server tells the client about the changed version so the client can update the version number of the data record. But at this point a network error occurs. So the client never gets the new version number.
5. User do changes on the data record and synchronizes the data again. And now a sync conflict occurs because client version is still 001 und server version is 002. In a "server always win" environment **the client data record is eliminated.**

Comment: You probably need a 2 phase commit. Once the server generates the new version number and this new version is successfully committed to the client only then should you commit the 'transaction' on the server. If it fails to transfer the version to the client you should rollback the transaction. This way on the next sync the versions will still be the same and you won't lose client side changes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes that is logically absolutely correct. But in my understanding, Azure App Service does not support transaction based sync: See this question from me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44825453/azure-app-service-offline-sync-pullasync-transaction . Conclusion from this question is that Azure App Service does not support transactions. 
Can you concrete your suggestion regarding to Azure App Service?